# Matplotlib v0.99 Surface with contour: zdir doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot function f(x,y)=(x+2)*y^2 with some iso level curves projected on x-y plane. The code I used is this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
import pylab as p


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X = np.arange(0, 2.5, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(0, 2.5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = ((X+2))*(Y**2)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3, cmap=cm.jet)
cset=plt.contour(X,Y,Z,zdir='z',offset=0)


ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 30)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

My problem is that zdir doesn't work, that is the contour lines are on the surface and not on x-y plane.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think `zdir` does what you think it does.  Try `zdir='x'` and look at the result.  `offset` defines the location of the plane of the projection.  What surface do you want it projected onto if not the x-y plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine for me (matplotlib 1.0.1).
[image]

Btw: It seems that [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html) example was added to gallery with matplotlib 1.0. Maybe this is a problem the previous version?

Comment: This is what I wanted to do. I guess I should install version 1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

`zdir` defines the direction to project.  (`zdir='x'` projects along the x axis)  `offset` defines the location of the plane to be projected onto (along the axis defined by `zdir`)

[Example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html)

I'm going to guess what you want is:

```
cset=plt.contour(X,Y,Z,zdir='z',offset=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

-> xs and ys: These are coordinates for x and y axes
-> zs: This is the value(s) for z axis. It can be one for all points or one for each point
--> zdir: This will choose what will be the z-axis dimension (usually this is zs, but can
be xs or ys)